# {USB Composite Device Kernel Module Driver Programming} Multiple Interfaces management and "no endpoint" handling

Tags: c, linux, usb, linux-device-driver

I'm Trying to port Pololu's mini maestro USB Servo Controller driver into a Linux Kernel Module (This is my first try of writing a kenel module). Pololu's Linux Driver actually uses mono runtime environment, lots of what I think are compatibilization layers and It's written in C# (Unknown for me), so porting it to C for compiling this into a kernel module it's important because I want other programs to use pipes to communicate with the USB Module.

So, here's the deal, I used lsusb -vvv to list the [Device Characteristics](http://justpaste.it/dod9)

But the last interface states:

```
 Interface Descriptor:
  bInterfaceNumber        4
  bNumEndpoints           0
  bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
  bInterfaceSubClass      4
  bInterfaceProtocol      1
  iInterface              2 Pololu Mini Maestro 18-Channel USB Servo Controller
```

What I can't figure out is:

- Is there a Non-listed Control endpoint that can be used for configuring Device mode?
- Can I handle it and how I can do it?

From the Composite device itself:

- A kernel driver instance is ran for each Interface?
- How can I catch an interface and identify how to manage it?
- How can I treat Interface Associations?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some answers to your questions:

> Is there a Non-listed Control endpoint that can be used for
>   configuring Device mode? Can I handle it and how I can do it?

The control endpoint will always be endpoint 0, you simply direct your setup packets to this endpoint to communicate a control request to the device. Since there is only one endpoint per device you will need to see how Polulu specifies the interface for the specified control request, typically passed in as the wIndex value for the control transfer.

> From the Composite device itself: A kernel driver instance is ran for
>   each Interface? How can I catch an interface and identify how to
>   manage it? How can I treat Interface Associations?

Each interface will present itself as some unique USB interface. Each one is independent and will have it's own behavior. For example you could have a composite device with 3 interfaces: an interface for a Mass Storage device, an interface for a USB Audio device and a Vendor Specific interface. Each one of these would load their own driver instances specifically for that interface. The first two will typically already be built in to modern OS and kernel versions since they are defined USB Classes. But the vendor specific device will probably have to do some VID/PID matching for a vendor specific driver. This is what will happen in your case if you need to talk to this particular interface you have shown above.

Comment: How can I see which interface am I handling? (from the driver perspective). As far as I know, the VendorID (VID) and ProductID (PID) are shared by the 5 Interfaces or the VID/PID It's unique for each Interface?

Comment: Yes, the VID/PID will exist for the physical device as a whole (composite device), but each interface will represent a sort of logical device. From a raw perspective you can ask the USB device for it's configuration descriptor to get the total number interfaces. Then you can loop through and ask for each interface descriptor and examine it. If you are creating a driver for some specific device, `usbserial` for example, the callbacks you register for your device will pass you some structures. From there you can look in to those to determine the number of the interface you are talking to.

Comment: You might look in to libusb as well, from there you can just access your device without the kernel driver part. Depending on what you want to do this may be enough for you to move forward.

Comment: I know that libusb might be easier or safer, But I'm really interested in Kenel Module Programming, It's like my first time

Answer (score 0):

So, I've digged in a couple of websites, and Asked on the [Pololu forum](http://forum.pololu.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=7786&p=36921) And I got some answers, First at all thanks to @preston for his clues!

- Can I handle it {the non-listed control endpoint} and how I can do it?

Yes, we can, via the `usb_control_msg` [function](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/usb/API-usb-control-msg.html), defined in line 132 of [/drivers/usb/core/message.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/core/message.c#L132)

> int usb_control_msg(struct usb_device *dev, unsigned int pipe, __u8 request,
>                      __u8 requesttype, __u16 value, __u16 index, void *data,
>                    __u16 size, int timeout)

- A kernel driver instance is ran for each Interface?

As @preston Replyed, it is

- How can I catch an interface and identify how to manage it?

We don't need to 'catch' the interface, the interface is sent to probe to the kernel module:

`static int probe(struct usb_interface *interface, const struct usb_device_id *id)`

- How can I treat Interface Associations?

As I've been told I don't need to handle them in an special way, just recognize the Interface with the driver on the probe function